# PHP number_format error

Tags: php

I have a string like:

```
R$10,25
```

I need to convert it to:

```
10.25
```

I'm trying with:

```
$value = 'R$10,20';
$value_subs = str_replace(array('R', '$'), '', $value);
$value_formated = number_format($value_subs, 2, ',', '.');
```

After I will compare the `$value_formated` value with another to proceed the code, like:

```
$another_value = 20.40;
if($value_formated <= $another_value)
{
    //Error
}
else
{
    //Proceed
}
```

But I receive the error ***A non well formed numeric value encountered***.
How to achieve this? Having in mind that I receive the value of the `$value` variable from the client, so, anything can be present here, but I just will pass it if aren't according with `if($value_formated <= $another_value)`.

Comment: replace the comma `,` to a dot `.` .  You are comparing `10,20 <= 20.40`

Comment: @roullie they're working with floats, not strings

Comment: @roullie Alright, but the error remains and if I use $value_subs = floatval($value_subs); as mentioned in the answer below, I get 10.00, not 10.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

combining @Hayden Schiff 's answer

```
<?php

    $value = 'R$10,20';
    $value_subs = str_replace(array('R', '$',','), array('','','.'), $value);
    $value_formated = floatval($value_subs);

    $another_value = 20.40;
    if($value_formated <= $another_value)
    {
        echo "Less or equal";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Greater";
    }
```

replace `,` to a `.` then parses the result to a float

Comment: That's nice, but this shows 20 instead 20.00. Is there a way to show with dot and zeros?

Answer (score 0):

The comma isn't the default decimal separator in PHP, that's why only the integer part is taken in account (since the comma isn't seen as a part of a number).

To solve the problem, you need to replace this comma with a dot.

A way:

```
$str = strtr($str, ['R' => '', '$' => '', ',' => '.']);
echo number_format($str, 2, ',', '.');
```

Note: using `strtr` in place of `str_replace` may be interesting to avoid a circular replacement if, for example, you want to remove dots used as thousand separator from the original string without to affect the decimal separator:

```
$str = strtr('R$100.000.000,25', ['R' => '', '$' => '', ',' => '.', '.' => '']);
echo number_format($str, 2, ',', '.');
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I've already accepted roullie's answer!